# Flutter_vlc_player and stream URL raspberry pi 4(webcam USB)

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi

I am trying to see the image of a USB camera of my Raspberry pi but I am not able because I do not know how I get my stream URL of Raspberry pi and in addition the code is giving me an error in **defaultHeight: 480, defaultWidth: 640** , Can anyone help me with these two questions? thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
void main() {runApp(MyApp());}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Raspberry Pi 4 stream'),
    );}}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _streamUrl;
  VlcPlayerController _vlcPlayerController;
  @override
  void iniState(){
    super.initState();
    _vlcPlayerController = new VlcPlayerController();
  }
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _streamUrl = 'http://192.168.1.14:8081';
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title),),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _streamUrl == null
                ? new Container(
             child: RichText(
               text: TextSpan(
                 children: [
                   TextSpan(
                       text: 'stream closed',
                         style: TextStyle(
                             fontSize: 14,
                             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                             color: Colors.white,
                             background: Paint()..color = Colors.red,
                         ),
                   )
                 ]
               ),),): new VlcPlayer(
              defaultHeight: 480,
              defaultWidth: 640,
              url: _streamUrl,
              controller: _vlcPlayerController,
              placeholder: Container(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),);}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no `defaultHeight` and `defaultWidth` parameter for [VlcPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player#api). What you can do is put that widget in a SizedBox to adjust the width and height:

```
new SizedBox(
    height: 480,
    width: 640,
    child: new VlcPlayer(
        controller: _vlcPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
        url: _streamUrl,
        placeholder: Container(),
    ),
)
```

I am not sure what software or service you are using for the Raspberry Pi side. According to that, you need to enter the stream url inside the app. Make sure that your Raspberry Pi and smartphone are in the same network.

I'm guessing that you used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPcuBo5QAW4) video to write this code. It also explains that you need to use [**Motion**](https://motion-project.github.io/) on the Raspberry Pi side.

Good luck!

***Edit***: Below is my code so you can try this one;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class LiveStream extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_LiveStreamState createState() => _LiveStreamState();
}

class _LiveStreamState extends State<LiveStream> {

VlcPlayerController _liveController;
final String _url = "YOUR_STREAM_URL";

@override
void initState() {
    _liveController = new VlcPlayerController(
            onInit: () {}
    );
    super.initState();
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _back,
    child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Text("Live View"),
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: _back,
            ),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadiuscircular(2),
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 400,
                            height: 300,
                            child: new VlcPlayer(
                                url: _url,
                                controller: _liveController,
                                aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                                placeholder: Container(
                                    height: 250,
                                    child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),),],
                                    )
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: _play,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
                        label: Text("Click to watch", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),)),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    )
);
}

Future<bool> _back() async {
    if (_liveController.initialized) {
        print("Disposing...");
        _liveController.dispose(); // to ensure disposing of the liveController to free up resources
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
}

void _play() {
    print(_liveController.initialized);
    if (_liveController.initialized) {
        _liveController.play();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes I am using this video and I have on the same network but still do not see the image(I am using a USB camera).

Comment: Can't really help you with the Raspberry Pi side, maybe if you could give more details like what service did you use, what steps did you apply or configurations? Are you sure that your Raspberry Pi's IP address is 192.168.1.14?
You can check that with `ifconfig` command. Are you getting any errors from Flutter that says something like *Your input can't be opened* ?

Comment: i this is not my IP but in my program has my IP
And when I run the program, this is what you give me on the console, but on my emulator I don’t do anything

Comment: console:`
creating player instance using shared library
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'registerChannels' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: registerChannels(0)
#0 Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1_VlcPlayerState._onPlatformViewCreated(package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart:105:17)
#2_UiKitViewState._createNewUiKitView(package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_view.dart:635:35)
<asynchronous suspension>
...`

Comment: I'm not sure what **registerChannels** method is. Obviously it causes the error. Don't forget to `dispose()` your VlcPlayer to save up memory. Read [this page](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player#-readme-tab-) to learn more about this package. Try **not to** hot reload. Stop your app and run it again to avoid any memory errors. I dealt with this package a lot lately, it is better to stop and run your app again. I will share my code on the answer, maybe you can try to apply that.

Comment: hello I tested your code and gave me what’s in the photo

Comment: Remove `final Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;` and `final bool isLandscape = orientation == Orientation.landscape;` declarations. Also `primary: !isLandscape` line which is in `Scaffold`. They are irrelevant, i will remove them from the code also.